# Updated via form OnetoOneField - Duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I am creating an app in which a user can create a `project` and each project has one-and-just-one `set of questions` (i.e. a form - I called it Firstquestions).

I want the user to be able to edit/update this `set of questions` via a form.
However, I get the error:
`duplicate key value violates unique constraint`

I am using PostgreSQL

**projects/models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    developer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**projects/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Regarding the projects
    path('allprojects', views.allprojects, name='allprojects'),
    path('createproject', views.createproject, name='createproject'),
    path('<int:project_id>', views.projectdetail, name='projectdetail'),
    path('<int:project_id>/editproject', views.editproject, name='editproject'),
    path('<int:project_id>/deleteproject', views.deleteproject, name='deleteproject'),
    #Regarding the set of questions
    path('<int:project_id>/', include('firstquestions.urls')),

]
```

**firstquestions/models.py**

```
class Firstquestion(models.Model):
    first_one = models.TextField()
    first_two = models.TextField()
    first_three = models.TextField()
    first_four = models.TextField()
    first_five = models.TextField()
    first_six = models.TextField()
    first_seven = models.TextField()
    developer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.OneToOneField(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**firstquestions/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('questionstoanswer', views.questionstoanswer, name='questionstoanswer'),
    path('firstquestionsdetail', views.firstquestionsdetail, name='firstquestionsdetail'),
    path('firstquestionsedit', views.firstquestionsedit, name='firstquestionsedit'),

]
```

**MY EDIT FUNCTION**

**firstquestions/views.py**

```
@login_required
def firstquestionsedit(request, project_id):
  project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST['first_one'] and request.POST['first_two'] and request.POST['first_three'] and request.POST['first_four'] and request.POST['first_five'] and request.POST['first_seven']:
      question = Firstquestion()
      question.first_one = request.POST['first_one']
      question.first_two = request.POST['first_two']
      question.first_three = request.POST['first_three']
      question.first_four = request.POST['first_four']
      question.first_five = request.POST['first_five']
      # question.first_six = request.POST['first_six']
      question.first_seven = request.POST['first_seven']
      question.developer = request.user
      question.project = project
      question.save()
      messages.success(request, 'Answers for User Centered Design questions have been edited')
      return redirect('/projects/allprojects')
    else:
      return render(request, 'firstquestions/firstquestionsedit.html', {'error':'All fields are required.'})
  return render(request, 'firstquestions/firstquestionsedit.html', {'project':project})
```

Comment: For a start, you should be using a Django form. A modelform will do most of this work for you, including validation and saving.

Comment: Many thanks, can you be more precise when you say "modelform"? I am new to Django

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this one ..

```
 @login_required
    def firstquestionsedit(request, project_id):
      project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
      if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['first_one'] and request.POST['first_two'] and request.POST['first_three'] and request.POST['first_four'] and request.POST['first_five'] and request.POST['first_seven']:
          question = Firstquestion.objects.filter(project=project).first()
          question.first_one = request.POST['first_one']
          question.first_two = request.POST['first_two']
          question.first_three = request.POST['first_three']
          question.first_four = request.POST['first_four']
          question.first_five = request.POST['first_five']
          # question.first_six = request.POST['first_six']
          question.first_seven = request.POST['first_seven']
          question.save()
          messages.success(request, 'Answers for User Centered Design questions have been edited')
          return redirect('/projects/allprojects')
        else:
          return render(request, 'firstquestions/firstquestionsedit.html', {'error':'All fields are required.'})
      return render(request, 'firstquestions/firstquestionsedit.html', {'project':project})
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem now is that when I update `first_six` I get the error `MultiValueDictKeyError at /projects/5/firstquestionsedit`

Comment: i think you are not passing 'first_six' key with post request.

Comment: Thanks, it was in the html. I forgot to pass the `name="first_six"`